# Python adding every other item

Tags: python

If I have a list with say `[7,6,5,4,3,2,1]` how can I make it add upp every second number, for instance `7 + 5 + 3 + 1`?

I've tried adding `mylist[0] + mylist[2]` etc but it is very tedious.

Answer (score 11):

```
sum(mylist[::2])
```

the `mylist[::2]` takes every other item, and `sum` sums it.

If you want to have the first, third, fifth et cetera item, you can use:

```
sum(list[1::2])
```

This will first omit the first item (with the `1` part), then do the same as in the first command.

Comment: You can use `sum(mylist[1::2])` to add every odd items.

Comment: Note: if you are dealing with huge lists or you are already memory constrained you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) instead of plain slicing: `sum(islice(mylist, 0, len(mylist), 2))`. This will only take as much memory as one element instead of creating a whole copy.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create a new list you can use xrange adding every even indexed element:

```
l = [7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

print(sum(l[i] for i in xrange(0, len(l), 2)))
```

Or use `itertools.islice`:

```
sum(islice(l, 0, None, 2))
```

Some timings show islice wins on time and space using python2:

```
In [14]: timeit sum(islice(l, 0, None, 2))
10 loops, best of 3: 123 ms per loop

In [15]: timeit sum(l[i] for i in xrange(0,len(l), 2))
1 loops, best of 3: 363 ms per loop

In [16]: timeit sum(l[::2])
10 loops, best of 3: 148 ms per loop
```

And they all return the same result:

```
In [21]: sum(islice(l, 0, None, 2))
Out[21]: 24999995000000

In [22]: sum(l[i] for i in xrange(0,len(l), 2))
Out[22]: 24999995000000

In [23]: sum(l[::2])
Out[23]: 24999995000000
```